# How secure is web page that has text mime type and contains _any_ user input

Tags: javascript, security, web, mime-types

I have a web server that returns content based on user input. I want to return the content with **Content-Type: text/text;** but I'm not sure how secure is it.

I did a test with Content-Type: text/text; and the browser just displays the content(doesn't interpret it at all) but maybe is a way to trick the it, I'm not a security expert.

thanks

Comment: everything in the browser transported via HTTP (including XMLHttpRequest) is text. It is insecure by nature.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is not secure to trust the browser interpreting the content-type - found more info here - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97241/does-a-content-type-text-plain-header-protect-against-xss-in-browsers?noredirect=1&lq=1